# math.round on double

Tags: vb.net, double, rounding

i wrote a very simple routine for an excel file. this is it

```
    Private Sub cmdCalc_Click()

     fyra = 100 - CDbl(txt4.Value)
     per = 100 - CDbl(txt5.Value)
     x = (CDbl(txt2.Value) + CDbl(txt3.Value)) / fyra
     y = x / per
     txt6.Value = Math.Round(y,2)

   End Sub
```

all the variables are declared as doubles. I can't understand why the result is 0. If i remove the Math.Round i get the number

Comment: What is the value of `y` before calling `Math.Round`?

Comment: it is for example 8.383838. the thing is when i insert the data to excel i get the number 8.84E-04 witch is 0.000883838383838384. why is this happening. if i do the math with the calculator the result is still 8.383838

Comment: It's a precision issue...

Comment: what can i do to correct it?

Comment: The actual value is: `8.838383946567774E-4` in double... When you Round: `0.000883838383838384` to the tenth it is `0`... Change your type to `Decimal` and use `Decimal.Round` to keep your precision.

Comment: i'm trying to declare variables as decimals but i get an error. i write dim x,y.... as Decimal.

Comment: `i'm trying to declare variables as decimals but i get an error` I can't see the error from here... Please update your question with this error you are receiving...

Comment: after writing declare x as decimal it marks it red and i get the message compile error expected new or type name

Comment: Source code characters occur that are not recognizable as a type name. The context calls for either an elementary data type or a declared element name representing a type. Please check that type is defined **and the type name is correctly spelled**...